# How to use stat on a file within a loop in bash programming

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to take a folder name through the prompt and perform task like get file size or read lines in files in a for loop but I keep getting error on the functions applied in the loop.

I have tried to use stat and cat but got the same error 
`cat/stat: test.js: No such file or directory`

```
read -p "Please provide the folder name; " FOLDERNAME
COUNT=0
SIZE=0
EACH=0
if [ -d "$FOLDERNAME" ]
then
    FILES=$(ls $FOLDERNAME )
    echo "checking $FOLDERNAME folder "
    for FILE in $FILES
    do
         echo "$FILE"
         echo $(cat $FILE)
        #  $(stat -c%s $FILE)
        #  echo $EACH
        #  (($SIZE=$SIZE+$EACH))
        ((COUNT++))
    done
    echo "You have $COUNT files in the $FOLDERNAME"
    # echo "$(stat $FOLDERNAME | grep Size  | tail -1  | cut -f1)"
    echo $(stat -c%s "$FOLDERNAME")
    echo "$SIZE"
else
    echo "$FOLDERNAME is does not exist"

fi
```

The program is runs as thus

```
Hello World!
Please provide the folder name; test
checking test folder 
test.c
cat: test.c: No such file or directory

test.css
cat: test.css: No such file or directory

test.js
cat: test.js: No such file or directory

test1.txt
cat: test1.txt: No such file or directory

test2.txt
cat: test2.txt: No such file or directory

test3.txt
cat: test3.txt: No such file or directory

You have 6 files in the test
4096
0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Avoid parsing the output of `ls`.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) Instead, you can get file names with a simple `*` glob and store them in an array variable:

```
FILES=("$FOLDERNAME"/*)
for FILE in "${FILES[@]}"; do
     echo "$FILE"
     cat "$FILE"
done
echo "You have ${#FILES[@]} files in the $FOLDERNAME"
```

An array is nice because it'll preserve any file names that contain spaces or other special characters. It also gives you an easy to way to count the files with `${#FILES[@}}` so you don't need the `$COUNT` variable.

Note that `echo $(<command>)` is a convoluted way of writing simply `<command>`. If you're going to capture a command's output just to echo that output, cut out the middle man and simply run the command directly.

(If you're wondering why your script doesn't work, it's because `ls` doesn't print `$FOLDERNAME` in front of each file. It simply prints the file names without their parent directory. The glob version above doesn't have that problem.)

Comment: Maybe also suggest lowercasing the variable names so as to avoid surprises when an uppercase variable name happens to be reserved for something crucial.